# VB.net Drawing rectangle in the center of the form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drawing

Good morning community

I want to draw a rectangle exactly in the center of the form. Also, I want draw under this rectangle some text.

With the text I think that I don't have a problem, I use the following code:

```
Dim sf As New StringFormat
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

        ' Line with the problem
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Beige, CInt(Local_Form.Width / 2), CInt(Local_Form.Height / 2), 200, 100)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Local_Text, _
                              New Font(MyCloud.Settings.Settings_Forms.Font.Name, 30), _
                              Brushes.GreenYellow, _
                              Local_Form.Width / 2, Local_Form.Height / 2, sf)
```

[image]

But, I have problems with the rectangle. Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things, the first is that you are setting your upper left corner of your rectangle to the center, you need to subtract half of your width and and half of your height from your Top and Left position. Also you should be using the [`ClientRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the actual working surface without the Chrome.

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Beige, CInt(Local_Form.ClientRectangle.Width / 2) - 100, CInt(Local_Form.ClientRectangle.Height / 2) - 50, 200, 100)
```

Comment: Perfect!, thanks Mark... works lovely.

I have another question related to that: I can calculate the width of the string? I want resize the rectangle depending of the string.

Comment: @MiBol use e.graphics.measurestring